# Is it possible to reuse code for integration and unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, language-agnostic, tdd, integration-testing

I work with a distributed system that has unit and integration tests. I am trying to save time and maintenance efforts by reusing code between integration and unit tests. For this I implemented an interface and 2 classes: fake and real. *Fake* class returns some stubbed data, and *real* class makes a few calls to other distributed services.

Current structure of my projects

```
/BaseTest              
   interface IFoo
-------------------------------------
/UnitTest
   class FakeFoo : IFoo

   [TestFixture]
   class FooTest {...} //uses FakeFoo
-------------------------------------
/IntegrationTest
   class RealFoo : IFoo

   [TestFixture]
   class FooTest {...} //uses RealFoo
```

I want to somehow reuse code for both tests, so if I have a test

```
[Test]
public void GetBarIsNotNullTest()
{
    var foo = IoC.Current.Resolve<IFoo>();
    Bar actual = foo.GetBar();
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);   
}
```

I want this test to run with both implementations: `RealFoo` and `FakeFoo`. So far I thought about copy-pasting tests between */UnitTest* and */IntegrationTest* projects, but this doesn't sound right.

System is written in C#, but I believe this question is language agnostic.

**Anyone has better ideas? Am I doing this wrong?**

Comment: Why not move the content of the tests into a shared library, and then call this from separate tests?

Comment: I think you're right -- see my comments below on your answer; my question is how to get this to work with regular MS Test framework (vs2012)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Even though others had good points in their answers, this is what I ended up doing**

I created a base class for unit and integration tests

```
[TestFixture]
public class FooBase
{
    [Test]
    public void GetBarIsNotNullTest()
    {
        var foo = IoC.Current.Resolve<IFoo>();
        Bar actual = foo.GetBar();
        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);   
    }

    //many other tests  
}
```

And then two derived classes from the `FooBase`. These class will only have the `SetUp` and nothing else. i.e.:

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTestFoo : FooBase
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        IoC.Current.Register<IFoo, FakeFoo>();        
    }

    //nothing else here
}

[TestFixture]
public class IntegrationTestFoo : FooBase
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        IoC.Current.Register<IFoo, RealFoo>();        
    }

    //nothing else here
}
```

So if I now run my tests, I get the tests defined in the parent class `FooBase` run twice for unit tests class and integration tests class with their own *real* and *fake* objects. This works because of the inheritance of the test fixtures.

Comment: Where do you fill database tables, required by `RealFoo`, or `RealRepository` used by `RealFoo`?

Comment: How will you test scenario, where `foo.GetBar()` returns null?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Currently I use an in-memory RavenDB instance that is started manually and filled from the tests. I am still working on how to automate this. For your second point, in my case that would be exceptional situation and the test must fail. Also I do use mocks for tests, it is just there is a place where fake serves better.

Comment: ok, how your container resolve what records should be in database for *current scenario*? Same for mocks. How your DI container set-ups mocks differently for each separate test?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky that is the catch. If I need *different* scenarios, I use mocks, and separate integration tests. But if the scenarios are the *same* both for unit tests and integration tests, this is where I use IoC and fakes. My IoC doesn't touch mocks, coz I think it is impossible to do that (or it will look really really weird).

Comment: oleksii, frankly speaking I still can't imagine scenarios where you can use same tests for integration and unit testing. But another point from me - if you move your `Arrange` part out of test, test context becomes unclear for developers.

Comment: I will second @oleksii -- we may not be talking about be "pure" unit testing anyway but rather different levels of integration testing, but if I write a Contract (interface) I want to be able to test it directly (calling the `.Core` implementation with mock repositories etc) and an API implementation (via webhosted WCF proxy client using real repositories).  Because I have (almost) the same input/cleanup methods exposed through the Contract, I can set-up and tear-down tests identically in both scenarios, and the results should be identical.

Comment: ex) `My.Contracts.ICompanyDirectoryService.AddMember`, `.RemoveMember`, `.GetDetails`, `.Filter`.  Test "directly" with:
1. `My.Core.CompanyDirectoryService.AddMember(new Member(A))`
2. `Assert.AreEqual(..., My.Core.CompanyDirectoryService.GetDetails())`
3. `Assert.Contains(memberA, ...Service.Filter(all))`
4. `Assert.IsTrue(...Service.RemoveMember(memberA.Id))`
5. `Assert.NotContains(memberA, ...Service.Filter(all))`

-----

Repeat with hosted api `http://mycodirectory.com/AddMember`, `/GetDetails/mem_a_id`, etc -- both uses should return the same results.

Answer (score 2):

There's something terribly wrong about your test scenarios.

Let's see unit-tests first. You have a dependency stub that give predictable results. You have CUT which should give *expected* results according to stub configuration. So far so good.

But. If you want to reuse your test code (your assertions) for your integration testing, that in fact means that you are expecting your *real dependency implementation* to produce same results as you stub did in your unit tests. If that's so, why don't you just test your dependency to give those results and skip whole layer of code?

**Update**

Your example is wrong. `FakeFoo` is a stub, and being that should *not* be tested. You do stubs to test classes that *depend* on some services. So let's assume that you are testing some class `Bar` that depends on `IFoo`, which means:

```
[Test]
public void GetBarIsNotNullTest()
{
    var bar = IoC.Current.Resolve<Bar>();
    var actual = bar.GetDon();
    Assert.IsNotNull(actual);   
}
```

and you are using different implementations of `IFoo` in your tests.

**To clarify my position**

Because you're copying your Act and Assert stages in your test, you are most likely testing the same code path in your *CUT* (`Bar`). That means test duplication and is no better than code duplication.

You should make sure that your CUT (`Bar`) is good on all code paths by using fakes (that will be unit-testing). Then you should make sure that your *dependency* (`RealFoo`) returns expected data (that will be integration-testing, because it works with distributed services). There's no need to test `Bar` with `RealFoo`, because it is already fully tested.

Comment: I don't necessarily expect results to be exactly the same. For example an operation should return an object with certain qualities, like *not-null*. What shall I do in this case? Am I correct that you suggesting to do the integration tests only? I probably didn't get it.

Comment: I talk about *assertions*, not results. When you test your operation for "certain qualities", it is an assertion. When you have two tests with same Act and Assert you are duplicating your code. I will clarify my proposition in post.

Comment: "You should make sure that your CUT (Bar) is good on all code paths by using fakes (that will be unit-testing). Then you should make sure that your dependency (RealFoo) returns expected data (that will be integration-testing...)"  The problem with this layered approach is that your integration testing may pass (assertions match service data) and your unit testing may pass (assertions match mock data), but the service data may not match the mock data.

Comment: It's easy for the expected data in these two testing layers to get out of sync, so there is value in testing all the way through, even if you are retesting a part. Call it integration testing, end-to-end testing, or whatever. Part of the reason to separate integration and unit tests is the long time integration tests take. You want unit tests to be quick so that a developer tests often.  Integration tests maybe run only on the CI/build machine.  Re-testing your "unit tests" as part of the bigger integration tests will not add significant time and will ensure the mock & real data are in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own fake implementations will not save your time. It's much easier to create mock of dependency:

```
Mock<IFoo> fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
```

And the worst part is setting-up your mock object. You can set-up different results for different test scenarios:

```
fooMock.Setup(f => f.Bar).Returns(true);
// or
fooMock.Setup(f => f.Bar).Returns(false);
```

This isn't possible with fake. You will have one implementation of `Bar` property, which will return either `true` or `false`.

UPDATE: The only difference between unit tests and integration tests is an `Arrange` part of test. `Act` and `Assert` could be the same (*if you do only state testing, without interaction testing*). But `Arrange` is completely different. It's not just creating instance of direct dependency. If you use mock, you should setup return result for members used by SUT. That will be enough to reproduce test scenario. But for real objects you should set all dependencies down the stack to some state, required by **current** test scenario.

Comment: Mocks are good, but if I use mocks I will need to re-write code for integration tests, this is what I am trying to escape. For some tests I do use mocks, but fakes are easier to be reused.

Comment: Again, you cannot use fakes for unit-testing, because you cannot setup different return results for stubbed member.

Comment: With regards to your update, you said the only part that is different is `Arrange`. And that is correct. I *arrange* via DI and IoC, so that it is a separate concern, and once a test resolve the correct dependency all the other steps are the same. Moreover, the `Resolve` step is the same because I use interfaces. The only thing that is different in my case is the `SetUp` where all the dependencies get registered

Comment: Arrange is not only part (*see italic*). See my questions to your post :)